# Are there any javascript rich text editors that work on the iphone/ipad?

Tags: javascript, iphone

Are there any javascript rich text editors (like tinymce) that work on the iphone/ipad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no HTML rich text editor that works on iOS.